# AspNetUsers link to another table. How to create object (1-1relationship)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, code-first, razor-pages

I'm trying to create a table with additional User info, and link it with User one-to-one relationship. I tried a few things found on stackOverflow, but still I can't properly link both tables (create object)

Idea of application is to review and rate beauty therapist. 
User can choose if he wants to have an extended account as therapist (with extra info and possibility to be rated).

I'm learning asp.net mvc so I'm open for any help or suggestions how to create this app.

When user is logged in and I try to create Therapist object, I have an error (looks like I must deliver user object). 
Not sure how to solve it or even if this solution for my idea is good.

```
public class Therapist
{     
        public int IdTherapist { get; set; }

        [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
        [Required]
        public string UserId { get; set; }

        public virtual  ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string TherapistName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Surname")]
        public string TherapistSurname { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "City")]
        public string City { get; set; } }

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{    

        public virtual Therapist Therapist { get; set; }
        public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
        {

            var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);

            return userIdentity;
        }
    }

//Therapist Controller

public ActionResult Create(Therapist therapist)      
   if (therapist.UserId == null)
               therapist.UserId = User.Identity.GetUserId();

                    _context.Therapists.Add(therapist);
                            context.SaveChanges();

                ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
            }

            return View(therapist);
```

After run this code, I have

> "System.Data.Entity.Validation.DbEntityValidationException", look closer: "ErrorMessage    "The User field is required."
>   (not User.Id)

Answer (score 0):

Try add a TherapistId property in User class.